# Adding pages to google webmaster tools by the bulk

Tags: google, google-search-console

Is there a method of adding websites in bulk to google webmaster tools?

My host username and password were hacked and all of my sites were injected with malicious scripts. I've cleaned everything up but the sites were d-listed and no longer show up in google search. I need to request reviews for ~150 sites but first I need to add them all to the webmaster tools.

Any non-tedious way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You can make a short [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) macro that reads the URL [from a CSV](http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling#Data_Input) file. Then run the macro in a [loop](http://wiki.imacros.net/Browser_Automation#Play_.28Loop.29_Button) 150 times.

Comment: Not a helpful answer, go buy 500 dollars of software...

Comment: iMacros which Frank linked to appears to be free, not $500

Answer (score 1):

You will not only need to add the websites, you will also need to add the webmaster tools verification code to each.

150 websites does not sound like a lot, you might spend a day doing it - but it will take you less time than writing scripts to do it for you. If you have friends who can help - just split the work and ask each of them to add the 50-75 websites on his list.

If you have 10,000+ websites to add ... then I would suggest writing some script to do it. But for just 150 manually is usually faster.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this is to use AutoIt. http://www.autoitscript.com/site/

You can set it up with a text file input, read in the file one line at a time and spit it into the web page form. I've used it for automated account deletion in business software, automated form fill for web forms, etc.

When you install AutoIt, it should create a folder C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\Extras\Au3Record which contains au3record.exe. This piece of software can record the key presses, mouse to text box and mouse clicks which it records in an AutoIt script. This script can then be modified to read read the text file, fill the field, click submit and then wait for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Generate sitemaps for all the sites, then submit the sitemaps through GWT. Alternatively, if you have your sitemaps setup correctly, then you can just submit the domain to GWT and Google will find the sitemap.