# Is there anyway to re-submit all sitemaps in Google Webmaster Tools at once for a domain?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, automation

[Something happened](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14121/google-webmaster-tools-says-my-xml-sitemap-appears-to-be-an-html-page/14124#14124) and I need to resubmit A LOT of sitemaps across a lot of domains.
Is there any way I can submit all sitemaps/all errorful sitemaps per domain even? It would make things easier for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [sitemapindex](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71453) for each domain that lists all sitemaps for that domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2011-01-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap2.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2011-01-01</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

This will prevent you from having to submit multiple sitemaps for each domain, at least. It also serves as a workaround for the 50,000 page limit for sitemaps, if you ever need to submit more 50,000 pages. (Each sitemap in the sitemap index can have up to 50,000 entries.)

Comment: I have many sitemapindexes with many sitemaps for each of our domains haha. And for some reason it's only working again if I resubmit each sitemap in a sitemapindex and then resubmit the sitemapindex itself

Comment: Make sure you change the `<lastmod>` date for any sitemaps you've updated. Otherwise they may not be be reindexed. You may also wish to read this answer/hack in regards to automating sitemap submission: [Adding pages to google webmaster tools by bulk.](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/adding-pages-to-google-webmaster-tools-by-the-bulk)

Comment: I'm not doing that and it seems to be working (for the most part). I'd prefer not to have to go threw each file and edit them (I will if I have to)